# php left join two mssql tables from two differents database

Tags: php, sql-server, left-join

I need to query data from two tables in different databases on the same server, but it always shows me the same error message:

> Warning: mssql_query(): message: Invalid object name 'db1.ARTICULO'.
>   (severity 16)

```
<?php 
$server = 'servidor\SQLEXPRESS';
$link = mssql_connect($server, 'usuario', 'password');
if (!$link) {
    die('Algo fue mal mientras se conectaba a MSSQL');
}   
$bd_1 = "db1";
mssql_select_db($bd_1, $link);

$link2 = mssql_connect($server, 'usuario', 'password',true);
if (!$link2) {
    die('Algo fue mal mientras se conectaba a MSSQL');
}   
$bd_2 = "db2";
mssql_select_db($bd_1, $link2);
$query = "SELECT ARTICULO.CODIGO, ARTICULO.NOMBRE, PRECIOS.PRECIO " ;
$query .= "FROM db1.ARTICULO LEFT JOIN db2.PRECIOS ON ARTICULO.CODIGO = PRECIOS.ARTICULO " ;
$query .= "WHERE ARTICULO.CODIGO = '" . $_POST["codart"] . "'";
$result = mssql_query($query);
?>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: To reference another database you need to use 3 part naming. The way you have this posted is you expect those objects to be in different schemas. You would need to use db1.dbo.ARTICULO if they are in the dbo schema.

Comment: You have a typo. You're connecting twice to $bd_1: mssql_select_db($bd_1, $link2);

Comment: mssql_select_db($bd_1, $link2); you should change the database to $db_2

Comment: I finally got it to work by using [schema]. Thanks a lot for the help :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In MSSQL, you need to specify the target as `[database].[schema].[object]`.

Change this line...

```
$query .= "FROM db1.ARTICULO LEFT JOIN db2.PRECIOS ON ARTICULO.CODIGO = PRECIOS.ARTICULO " ;
```

...to this...

```
$query .= "FROM db1.dbo.ARTICULO LEFT JOIN db2.dbo.PRECIOS ON ARTICULO.CODIGO = PRECIOS.ARTICULO " ;
```

Assuming this is all in the default `[dbo]` schema.

Comment: I finally got it to work by using [schema]. Thanks a lot for the help :-)

Comment: @osbragon Please accept the answer if this worked for you.  Thanks!